# Расстановка колонок в диаграмме

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

Использую библиотеку Highchart ,по коду вроде как все правильно прописал но вместо того чтоб у каждого столбика было свое название ,они все под фракцией *"-10 "*. Что не так то ?
Вот сам код ...
 **Возвращается запрос таким образом (взял для примера другой график и сделал по своему принципу ,*данные хранятся в переменных n_data1 ,n_data2 ,n_data3*  **

```
    function(data) {
var n_data1 = [205],
    n_data2 = [400],
    n_data3 = [290],
   dataLength = data.length,
                         i = 0;
                    for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
                    switch (data[i][1]) {
                                n_data1.push([
                               data[i][0] / 100, // var val1 
                                ]);
                                break;
                                n_data2.push([
                              data[i][0] / 100, // var val1 
                                ]);
                                break;
                                n_data3.push([
                              data[i][0] / 100, // var val1 
                                ]);
                                break;
default:
                        }
                    }
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2018'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank">statcounter.com</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },
    series: [
        {dataLabels: {enabled: true},
                                "name": "Окатыши",
                                "colorByPoint": true, 
                                colors: ['#4b0e0e',],
                                data: n_data1,
                            },
                                 {dataLabels: {enabled: true},
                                "name": "Окатыши",
                                "colorByPoint": true,
                                  colors: ['#0b4a0d',],
                                data: n_data2,
                            },
                                 {dataLabels: {enabled: true},
                                "name": "Окатыши",
                                "colorByPoint": true,
                                  colors: ['#1c165f',],
                                data:n_data3,
                            },
    ],

})};
```

**И скриншот** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какие данные, такой и график. разбирайтесь, что у вас в массивах `data`

Comment: Данные правильные ,но они все 5 столбиков почему-то под "-10" фракцией

Comment: А должны были разбиться под каждой ,равномерно

Comment: ну дак приведите [mcve] с данными, чтобы не гадать тут

Comment: Понял ,сейчас попробую скинуть

Comment: Уже залил похожий пример

Comment: у меня сомнения, что этот код может выполняться. он синтаксически не корректен. сделайте сниппет, добавьте там ссылки на cdn чартов, чтобы он реально график рисовал, а так у вас там какая-то анонимная функция, которая нигде не вызывается, и switch в котором нет кейсов, зато есть брейки.